# How do I standardize names like "Alice P S. T.Kong" to a format like "Alice P.S.T. Kong"?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have thousands of names in column `A` whose spacing and punctuation varies. How do I trim repeated white space, get exactly one period and no white space between initials, and have exactly one space after initials and before the last name?

| Names | Desired results |
| --- | --- |
| Ajay K Thapar | Ajay K. Thapar |
| Ajay K. Thapar | Ajay K. Thapar |
| A.T Chamberlain | A.T. Chamberlain |
| A. C. T. van Duin | A.C.T. van Duin |
| Alice P S Kong | Alice P.S. Kong |
| Alan T. K. Wan | Alan T.K. Wan |
| Alan T K Wan | Alan T.K. Wan |
| Alan T. K Wan | Alan T.K. Wan |
| Alan T K.Wan | Alan T.K. Wan |
| Alan T.K. Wan | Alan T.K. Wan |

Comment: .... and what is your exact question? It helps us if we know what to answer.

Comment: Is it realy not clear what I am asking?

Comment: Do you think _" I must standardize the spelling due to simple mistakes with white spaces and periods."_ is a clear enough assignment?

Comment: No, that's why I wrote 1,2 and 3 and added a table for clarity

Comment: Yet, you managed to do that without asking a single question. Be specific. What do you need help with? It also helps if you share your own code so we (the collective) know where to step in and provide guidance.

Comment: Edited to shorten and present a question. @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the replacement in 2 iterations. One of possible solutions:

1. Normalize dots and spaces after single letters, so that every single letter is followed by a dot and a space.

   pattern: `\b([A-Z])([\s.]+|$)`

   replacement: `$1.`
2. Strip spaces between multiple single letters.

   pattern: `\b([A-Z]\.) (?=[A-Z]\.)`

   replacement: `$1`

Comment: Google Sheets formulas use [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2). RE2 does not support lookarounds, so the latter expression will not work.

Comment: @doubleunary It worked for me. I tested it with "Find and replace" dialog, not with `regexreplace()` function.

Comment: That is interesting. The [Search and use find and replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) help page explicitly specifies RE2 whose [documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) states `(?=re) before text matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED`. But it indeed seems to work in the **Edit > Find and replace** dialog box.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to do this `/\b([A-Z])([\s.]+|$)/g,'$1. '` am I missing something?

Comment: i.e add a space after the `.`

Comment: This answer applies to the **Edit > Find and replace** dialog box. Your comment suggests that you are applying these regexes in Apps Script. The question does not specify Apps Script. If you need help with an Apps Script solution, you should post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), because once there are answers, you should not change requirements so that they invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(SPLIT(A1:A10, ". "), LAMBDA(x, TRIM(TEXTJOIN(, 1, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(x, "^[A-Z]$"), x&".", " "&x&" "))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Yet a bit of explanation wouln't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

In the event you need more complex transformations, it might be easiest to simply use nested `regexreplace()` functions. This formula will match the desired results you show:

```
=arrayformula( 
  regexreplace( regexreplace( regexreplace( 
    trim(A2:A11), 
    "\b(\w) ", "$1. " ), 
    "\. ", "." ), 
    "\.(\w\w)", ". $1" ) 
)
```

If you do not know the number of regular expressions to apply in advance, use this pattern:

```
=lambda(
  data, regexes, replaceWith, 
  byrow( 
    data, 
    lambda( 
      row, 
      if( 
        len(row), 
        reduce( 
          row, sequence(counta(regexes)), 
          lambda( 
            acc, regexIndex, 
            regexreplace( 
              acc, 
              index(regexes, regexIndex), 
              index(replaceWith, regexIndex) 
            ) 
          ) 
        ), 
        iferror(1/0)  
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  arrayformula(trim(A2:A)), 
  { "\b(\w) ", "\. ", "\.(\w\w)" }, 
  { "$1. ", ".", ". $1" }  
)
```

You can replace the two { array expressions } at the end with references to `filter()` formulas that fetch regular expressions from a range of cells.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Thank you, interesting to contrast (the first one) this with `player0` response